# cin not working in my code

Tags: c++

Error in line 9, 10 and 13
"no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std:istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion'"

```
#include <stdafx.h>  // I should have put #include "stdafx.h" instead
#include <iostream>  // My mistake was I didn't #include <string>

using namespace std;
    int main()
{
    cout << "This is the left step bitwise operation\n";
    string x;
    cin >> x;  // line 9
    cout << "You typed" << x;  //line 10
    string y;
    cout << "Enter second number please!"; 
    cin >> y; // line 13
    cin.get();
    return 0;
} // line
```

My vague guess is that I didn't #include something

Comment: You haven't included `<string>`.

Comment: By the way, since `stdafx.h` is local to the current project you should include it using double quotes, not angular brackets.

Comment: Curious you didnt get an error with `string x;` though.

Comment: Always look at the *first* error message first.  I bet it's something like "Error: missing semicolon before 'x' on line 8"

Comment: <iostream> also includes <string> in my experience.

Comment: @YoshiHi, In some implementations, yes. If I recall correctly, Visual Studio does some weird thing with it that causes behaviour like this. All in all, you can't count on it happening the same way in different implementations, so if you need something, include what you need for it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to `#include <string>`. Your code relies on that when you input a string, as well as when you declare it, and when you output it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string> <------
```

I can't take too much credit for this, so it's a community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

If you include a file from the same directory do not use angled quotes but use doubled instead.

`#include "stdafx.h"`

Also, include `<string>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"  
or move 
#include <stdafx.h>
add 
#include <string>
```